# R saving maximum of 10 characters per line

Tags: r, file

I am writing matrices to a text file. The problem is that any line longer than 10 characters is cut and added to the next line. I want it to all display in one line.

Example, basic info with a 1 x 12 matrix comes out as:

```
12 
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0
```

Goal:

```
12
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Code:

```
# Create all the info
info <- paste(inputSize)
inTheta <- matrix (0,1,inputSize)

# Create the file
file.create(fileDir)

# Write the content
write(x=info,file=fileDir,append=TRUE)
write(x=inTheta,file=fileDir,append=TRUE)
```

Comment: The `file.create` statement is unnecessary.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is the `ncolumns` parameter you can specify in the `write` function to make the line as long as you need:

```
write(m, "file.txt", append = T, ncolumns = 12)
```

This will give a file:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```